# How to use java 8 merge function for n number of hashmaps

Tags: java, string, java-8, java-stream

I need to merge n hashmaps ideally  in a loop like shown below using java 8 merge or something:

Map 1 : `{Name:XXX,Phn:123,Work:""}`

Map 2 : `{Name:XXX,Phn:456,Work: xyz}`

Map 3 : `{Name:XXX,Phn:789,Work:""}`

I would like to get an output like below :

```
{
   Name:XXX,        // if all values for a key are same take one
   Phn:123/456/789  // merge all non null values for same key
   Work:xyz         // make sure non-null values are never replaced
}
```

When I try to use putall like this

```
public Map<String,String> mergeOriginalDataMaps(List<Integer> indexList, List<Map<String,String>> originalData) {   
    Map<String,String> tmpMap = new HashMap<String,String> ();
    for (int index : indexList ) {
        tmpMap.putAll(originalData.get(index));
    }
    return tmpMap;
}
```

If the value of duplicate key is `""`, the previous value is replaced with the new one. I need to concatenate the values rather than replace them.

Comment: What does `123/456/789`  mean? Do you want a `Map<String, List<String>>` as result?

Comment: just need to concatanate the values...sorry for not being clear...

Comment: It looks like you should be using a custom class with 3 fields `name`, `phone` and `work` rather than a `HashMap`.

Comment: its not specific...i am trying to read a user input file content and the fields can be anything...

Comment: @nelz OK fair enough, but then don't you need to explain how to deal with the different keys? Is it only the `"Phn"` values that you want to concatenate?

Comment: i need to do it for all duplicate keys...just that i need to get all non null values for the duplicate keys concatanated...

Comment: You can probably simplify this if you do the processing as you are reading. For instance, you can throw out all keys without values. You can relatively easily check for uniqueness of values as well.

Comment: @pvg thats right i guess...@Tunaki many thanks for your time...

Answer (score 9):

If you have a `List<Map<String, String>>`, which represents a list of maps to merge, you can have

```
Map<String, String> result =
    maps.stream()
        .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            Map.Entry::getKey,
            Collectors.mapping(
                Map.Entry::getValue,
                Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.<String>toSet(), s -> String.join("", s))
            )
        ));
```

This flat maps each map into a Stream of its entries. Then the Stream is grouped by the value of each entry and all distinct elements with the same key are mapped to their value, joined.

The distinct part is made possible by first collecting all the values inside a `Set`.

---

Sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Map<String, String>> maps = new ArrayList<>();
    maps.add(new HashMap<String, String>(){{ put("Name", "XXX"); put("Phn", "123"); put("Work", ""); }});
    maps.add(new HashMap<String, String>(){{ put("Name", "XXX"); put("Phn", "456"); put("Work", "xyz"); }});
    maps.add(new HashMap<String, String>(){{ put("Name", "XXX"); put("Phn", "789"); put("Work", ""); }});

    Map<String, String> result =
        maps.stream()
            .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                Collectors.mapping(
                    Map.Entry::getValue,
                    Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.<String>toSet(), s -> String.join("", s))
                )
            ));

    System.out.println(result); // prints "{Phn=123456789, Work=xyz, Name=XXX}"
}
```

Comment: WOW ...  Thanks a lot...let me try to implement it this way!!